# Why is Skype using over 1 GB of iCloud backup data?

Tags: icloud, backup, storage, skype

A few weeks ago I began getting notifications warning me that I was running low on iCloud space. I didn't think much of it until I checked my iCloud backups.

[image: iPhone iCloud backup]

[image: iPad iCloud backup]

To my surprise, between my iPhone and iPad, Skype was inflating the size of my iCloud backups by over 1 GB.

Even more bizarre was that Skype's documents and data were using up 600 MB ***less*** on the devices themselves. (Screenshots from **Settings -> General -> Storage & iCloud Usage -> Storage -> Manage Storage**)

iPhone data

[image: Skype iPhone data usage]

iPad data

[image: Skype iPad data usage]

The low storage warnings stopped appearing once I stated excluding Skype data from my iCloud backups, but I'm still perplexed as to why it was using so much space to begin with.

**Is there a reason why Skype would need over 1GB of storage space?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are saving all conversations including attachments

Comment: Can I delete those conversations/attachments from my device without affecting the conversations on Skype for Desktop?

Comment: Sorry not sure but you could back up Skype on the desktop before trying

Comment: I've only ever used Skype for iPhone/iPad for video calling, so I'm assuming Skype have synced my attachments across devices. It would explain why both devices use around the same amount of local data.

Comment: So just exclude it from iCloud and jobs a good un

Comment: That doesn't prevent the app from taking up 350mb on my iPad. I'm also still perplexed as to why it would use nearly double the space in my iCloud backup.

Comment: Delete and reinstall my Skype only uses 100mb